# Making POST request to form that validates input?

Tags: javascript, forms, selenium

There is a form on a site that I'm trying to send a POST request to (from Python.)

Even when I provide the same params via Postman that I do via when using the form normally (grabbed params from Chrome console), there is a validation check which causes the request to not show the desired results. It seems to be attached to the button of the form:

`<button class="btn btn-default btn-primary" type="submit" onclick="return searchCheck(this);" id="searchBtn">Search</button>`

Seems like `searchCheck` validates the text provided in the HTML input form, which is presumably (?) be empty when I make POST requests without using a web browser. Is there any way I can make the POST request to mimic submitting the form *WITHOUT using a webdriver like Selenium* if the form has JS validation on the client side? Thanks so much!

For reference, below is the full `searchCheck` function found from the Chrome console:

```
function searchCheck(b) {
    var c = 2;
    switch (parseInt($("search_selection").value)) {
    case null:
    case false:
        return false
    }
    if ($("main_search").value.length < c) {
        var a = $("search_info").show();
        a.setStyle({
            opacity: 1
        });
        $("search_info_msg").update("minimum " + c + " chars required!");
        a.show();
        new Effect.Fade(a,{
            duration: 5
        });
        return false
    }
    b.className += " disabled";
    if (searchCloseTimer) {
        clearTimeout(searchCloseTimer)
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: All that function does is check that the input is longer than 2 characters, all client-side stuff.  That should not affect you trying to post the form.  Your postman stuff won't even encounter this function.

Comment: How is this question relevant to PHP?

Comment: Thanks for your responses!

@James: hmm, so I didn't suspect so as well -- but the response from the POST request from Postman had the "minimum 2 chars required!" error msg (as seen in the `searchCheck` function) instead of the actual results I wanted, which made me think that this function was being called.

@MagnusEriksson: The search form on the website is made using PHP, so I added it as a tag just in case -- perhaps it is not relevant to the question though, so I can remove it.